Is this TL431 based low battery cutoff circuit practical
I made a low battery cutoff circuit to monitor my 12v lead acid battery using TL431. I followed the circuit diagram shown below. Sorry for the hand-drawn schematic. I am however not satisfied with the outcome, since I understood with my little knowledge of TL431 that it would work better than a regular OpAmp based comparator. When I built the cutoff circuit using comparator, the relay vigorously oscillated between NO and NC around the cutoff voltage. I thought it will be different when using a shunt regulator like TL431. But unfortunately it is behaving the same.
First of all I am finding it really difficult to set the cutoff voltage at around 12.3v using the pot, I could set it to around 11.5v only. But then too, the relay starts turning on and off rapidly after 11.7v and finally cuts off below 11.5v. Can someone please suggest if I am doing something wrong in this circuit? I am not an electronics expert, so don’t have the knowledge if this behaviour is expected. I am aware of the better alternatives like a special purpose IC made just for this purpose or microcontroller based solutions. But I am just trying to learn the reality here. Are all those websites flooded with similar TL431 based cutoff circuits referring basically this end result? Most of them shows a MOSFET based load driver, but I slightly modified it to drive a relay, so that I get a buzzer based sound alert as well, when the battery voltage is lower than cutoff.
PS: I am using a 14Ah battery and a 10 watt led panel as load. I thought using a reasonable load will help the battery voltage to drop significantly under load that matches my practical use case.


Without looking over the schematic, the on/off chattering behavior is consistent with the lack of hysteresis.

Personally, I would do this circuit without the relay - a 1A load is easy to do a solid-state design that would be cheaper, more reliable, and efficient.

The TL431 is nothing more than an input-powered comparator.

Yes. This behavior is expected and the circuit will be unstable near the switching threshold. You need to add a concept called positive feedback to your design to make the transition more "snappy".
Since you already have the comparator, you likely needed to only add one component to your circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R2 is key. If you had your circuit almost working with the chattering, just add a highish value resistor from the output to the (+) input of the comparator. This will add the necessary hysteresis that your original circuit was lacking.
Your new circuit suffers from the same effect. This could be treated by adding additional circuitry to create the missing snap-action. I will include the corrections to your TL431 circuit if there is interest.
So back to the TL431 (corrected) circuit:

simulate this circuit
R8 and R15 are key. You're going to have to mess with the resistor values - I didn't do the math so take any values with a grain of salt.  If requested, I could add appropriate starting values.

One doesn't have access to the comparator output in the TL431.

OP had indicated in their question first paragraph they already had tried an circuit with a comparator so I think this answer was proposing to re-look at the comparator usage so that the hysteresis could be added.

Yes I can try on the comp design as well. But plz show the TL431 equivalent circuit if possible.

Sir, I tried first 2 schematics with OpAmps and the first one using TL431 with no success yet. The relay remains turned on always , shutdown is never triggered. I still feel the circuits are correct but it has something to do with the resistance values I chose because in TL431's on and off conditions the effective resistances on the feedback point greatly depends on whether I understood how it work properly. Can you please suggest what values you tried on simulator?

@MOSFET or atleast if you could briefly explain the working principle of the 1st TL431 circuit, that would help too.

@sribasu I didn't simulate or test anything. I was hoping you would be able to do that. But if I find time, I'll update the circuits with real calculated values that should get things working. How much hysteresis do you need? 300mV?

@MOSFET Yes that was my question - what is the relation between the hysteresis voltage and the Rₕₛₜ? In my case the load drops the battery voltage to almost 0.5V. Can I put a resistor value that would support this load with some additional headroom, so say 0.7V? Am I talking about burning any component with such expectation? :D

@sribasu It's going to be a bit tricky because the battery voltage depends on load. But for the circuit. Use R11 = 20K; R12 (pot) = 10K; R10 = 1k; Rhyst = 220k. These values will get you a turn on voltage of 11.7V and a turnoff voltage of 10.8V with the pot near the middle position. R7 = 68; R6 = 1K; R9 = 10k. These values should get you close but likely still need to be optimized. You may also need a 47k resistor from B-E on Q2 if the relay stays on.

Thanks for the values, I'll try these and let you know. Just asking - if I simply change "my circuit" a bit to connect the voltage divider for TL431's reference to a stable voltage source (resistor+8V zener in series), instead of connecting it directly to the battery source, does it help to get rid of the problem?

@sribasu Yes. It helps (it corrects your problem in the right direction). but it's still not going to be good enough in real life. Even in theory (infinite gain of TL431 and perfect reference), you will still have instability due to inherent noise while operating at the switching threshold. You need a window for a practical design (a different threshold voltage for the "turn on" and the "turn off" voltage levels). This idea is true for any "bang bang" design - electrical or otherwise. The particular case of infinite gain/bandwidth of the control element is only metastable in theory.

@sribasu I should also add that since the voltage of your battery drops appreciably under load, your going to need a big window to kill your accidental oscillator.

The logic to connect the voltage divider to a stable voltage source, which I asked in my last comment didn't work for obvious reason. The aim to toggle the relay based on the battery voltage, attaching the voltage divider to a stable voltage kills the purpose of the circuit. However your OpAmps based comparator circuit did work for me atlast. I was able to get the circuit work as expected and cutoff sharply without chattering using Rhyst~=100K. I actually used a POT to adjust and set it exactly where I needed it to set. It cutsoff at 12.3V and doesn't open until 12.9V which covers my need.

A better solution would be this. It uses no power when off, and integrates the on/off function into the low battery protection.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In order to inhibit switch on if the battery is low, the ON switch connects the input voltage to the voltage measuring divider chain via D3. If the input voltage is high enough, IC1 turns on. I've shown a PNP Q2 to boost IC1's output current into the relay, though it may be possible to drive a sensitive relay directly from the TLV431. It doesn't supply full voltage to the relay, it's trivial to reconfigure it as common emitter if that's needed. The relay turns on, connecting the load, and maintaining the input voltage via D2. The ON button can now be released. D2 prevents the ON switch from powering the load directly. D5 is the normal transient catcher for the relay when turning off.
The Texas TLV431 only works to 6v, so cannot be used here. The On Semi, Diodes Inc and Zetex versions are specified to 16v, so should be OK. I think TI may have released a higher voltage version with a different number. A TL431 goes to 36 V, though it needs more input current than the TLV version, so R9/10 would need to be rather smaller.
When coming to turn the circuit off, large capacitors in the load may hold the load voltage above the battery minimum threshold for long enough to be tedious, pressing the off button and waiting for it to stop. R11 allows you to actively load the output when turning off, choose a smaller value of R11 to discharge faster. The maximum current you can draw from the load is limited by R11 pulse load handling, D2 and the off switch current handling.
Use of D2 and D3 reduces the threshold accuracy slightly, but I don't think significantly. R9 and R10 are shown for approximately 11 V threshold, about the minimum for nominally 12 V lead acid batteries.
{edit} On reflection, the above circuit has been 'improved' beyond the point of usefulness, and the simpler one below might be closer to meeting the OP's needs.

simulate this circuit
What is better about it?
We can't sense the battery voltage under load until the load is connected. Therefore, there's no point in using D3 above to sense battery voltage before connection. If we are going to connect the load, we might as well connect it unconditionally.
Now, when we push the 'on' switch, the load turns on. No chattering relay, it will stay on for as long as the button is pushed. Once released, it will only stay on if the on-load battery voltage is adequate. Once it drops out, it will stay off.
This allows for two useful benefits. If the load draws a switch-on surge, for instance to charge capacitors, holding the on button for the duration will allow it to ride through the voltage dip. If the circuit is being used in a life-or-death situation and you do want to sacrifice battery life for functionality, say to keep a phone going when you need to call for help, pressing the on button continuously overrides the low voltage cutout.

I like your idea - clever using the relay as both the load control and the feedback. Only problem I see is there is no way for the circuit to activate on battery level. It requires a "start" switch. But the no power state is excellent.

This looks like a fascinating solution. I will certainly try this tomorrow morning and share the results. I have a concern with this though - "the ON switch connects the input voltage to the voltage measuring divider chain via D3. If the input voltage is high enough, IC1 turns on." What if the load is high enough to significantly drop the battery voltage (and the reference voltage) that the IC turns of immediately after starting? That's probably the "around threshold" zone. I did not understand how the circuit behaves when the battery voltage is in that zone during starting up.

@sribasu it would trip on and off until you released the on switch. It would need a little extra circuitry to make the 'on' edge rather than level triggered. I'll think about it overnight.

If I simply change "my circuit" a bit to connect the voltage divider for TL431's reference to a stable voltage source (resistor+8V zener in series), instead of connecting it directly to the battery source, does it help to get rid of the problem?

@sribasu 'the problem' is that the problem is not yet fully defined. That's the benefit, and the problem, with simply putting up a strawman circuit and seeing what it does. I am guilty of putting up a cute circuit to get people thinking, without having fully read and thought through your problem statement, which is the relay jittering at the threshold. Two solutions - hysteresis, though the size of that needs to be designed, or 'stays off', which needs memory, a D-latch or something. I could add a CMOS (zero power) D-latch so that 'on' is edge triggered, but it would destroy the simplicity.

@sribasu In fact the circuit is still missing some specified functionality to be useful. For instance, if the load has bulk storage capacitors on its rail, then the switch-on surge could dip the rail, even if the battery is good. The low battery 'off' needs a filter delay on it to ride through a switch on surge.

@sribasu I've added a variation of my circuit to the end of my answer, which behaviour might suit your needs better. No need to set hysteresis or surge delays, it's all done with the on switch and the user.

@Neil_UK thanks so much! This circuit almost covers the problem by cleverly utilizing the relay state. However, as you said in a state where the remaining charge in battery is just around the threshold voltage, the ON button has to kept pressed to keep the load connected. I will give it a try.

There are number of wrong things with that circuit...
The logic is inverted. The TL431 will pull the BD140 base down when the battery voltage goes above the set threshold, not when it goes below the threshold like you are expecting. You need to invert the logic that drives the transistor.
The relay in series with the BD140 emitter is not a good idea, the coil voltage appears as feedback on the BD140 base-emitter voltage and can turn off the transistor. The relay should on the collector side.
The relay should also have a freewheeling diode to protect the rest of the circuit from the back emf.
You also need to add hysteresis. You need to consider also that when the battery is connected to the load there is a high current draw and consequently a drop in the battery output voltage. Once the relay turns on that battery becomes unloaded so the voltage measured at the battery terminals will rise and this will result in oscillation.
Further, turning on a relay to indicate low battery charge is not a great idea. The relay coil draws a significant current and it will fully discharge the battery in a short time.

Thanks for taking time to respond. BD140 is a PNP transistor. The relay is on it's collector side only. And it turns off when the TL431shuts off below threshold pulling down the base of BD140. So, my relay coil is not 'ON' below the cutoff voltage. I think you thought BD140 is a NPN transistor. I missed to add the flyback diode in the schematic, but it is there in my circuit. My whole question was on how to tackle the hysteresis. Please shed some light on that.

@sribasu - The schematic in your question clearly shows the relay coil between +12V and the BD140 transistor emitter (terminal with the arrow indication). As Sailtronic indicated the relay coil should connect between GND and the collector side of the BD140.

My bad, I mean it's on the emitter side. I'll take this suggestion to put it on the collector side. But will that make any difference to the hysteresis related chattering I am talking about?

@sribasu Just to be clear, you want hysteresis to avoid the chattering. Lacking it is the reason for the chattering behavior.

First of all, you don't show fuses. Without fuses this circuit is a fire waiting to happen. You need two fuses: one for the load, and one for the undervoltage lockout. The latter must be much smaller than the former, because a short in the lockout will destroy the thin PCB traces and small components if it is allowed to draw as much current as F1 would allow. F2 should be 50-100mA.
TL431's reference voltage is 2.5V. So the nominal resistor ratio should be such that it produces 2.5V around the threshold voltage. Having two equal values in the divider wastes 4/5ths of the potentiometer's range. That's why it's so hard to adjust.
We also need hysteresis feedback for the TL431: once the undervoltage lockout gets triggered, we want it to stay triggered. Normally as the load gets disconnected, the battery voltage will rise a bit, and the TL431 would see the voltage as all right again. We need to counteract that.
Finally, keeping the idle current of the monitor circuit low would be nice.
The circuit below accomplishes these goals.

The current mirror Q1-Q2 drives a bit over 1mA of current into TL431. In contrast to a resistor that would drive several times more.

The current mirror Q4-Q3 generates a current proportional to the gate voltage, and draws it from the reference node (VR1 wiper). This provides hysteresis. As the gate of M1 swings high when the load is being turned off, more current is sunk from VR1, making the battery appear even more discharged to TL431.
R3 adjusts the magnitude of hysteresis. The lower R3, the larger the hysteresis. Conversely, the higher R3, the higher the hysteresis. Generally hysteresis should be adjusted in "large" steps, say each step being a factor of 1.5-2x change of R3 (whether increase - multiplying the resistance by the factor, or decrease - dividing the resistance by the factor).

The mosfet switches take no gate current, compared to a relay.

The whole circuit draws about 3mA of current.

When the load gets switched off, it pulls the gate of M2 low, activating the buzzer.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To make this circuit practical, we need one more step: permanent shut-down that reduces current consumption to <<1mA when the voltage drops low enough that the battery is considered dangerously discharged.

Well, the TL431 is like a comparator with an internal reference and external access only to the (-) input and, unfortunately, not the (+) input which is needed for hysteresis (positive feedback.)
But you can use two of them to create a window comparator, with added hysteresis.
One of them is used to compare against the low voltage limit. The other is used to compare against the high voltage limit.
For example:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ set the high-voltage threshold. \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ set the low-voltage threshold. Note that \$R_3\$ is arranged here to provide \$1\:\text{mA}\$ to the left-most TL431 and so \$R_4\$ is calculated for the low-voltage threshold from there. \$R_5\$ also provides about \$1\:\text{mA}\$ to the right side TL431.
Feedback occurs through \$R_7\$ and \$R_8\$.
Here's an LTspice run where I specify operation circa \$11.8\:\text{V}\$ and \$12.2\:\text{V}\$:

\$Q_1\$ drives the relay. (I used a dummy resistor load in the LTspice run and did not use a relay device there.)
This also shows the hysteresis.
This is only a behavioral example, though. There are additional details having to do with driving a relay. But it may offer a direction to consider.

Sir regarding this statement - "The buzzer should sound when the source voltage isn't within the window. The load will be powered when the source voltage is within the window." Does it solve the problem of chattering? Just from reading it seems like it just provides an additional high voltage cutoff, but my aim is to get rid of relay chattering around any of the thresholds. Please can you help me understand how that is addressed with this circuit?

@sribasu Sorry, I didn't get all my thoughts down. I had been thinking about using some feedback. I'll add that to the answer. Apologies.

@sribasu The idea is added. It's only a basic behavioral pointer. Details matter and you'll need to work those out in your case.
